# CodeIgniter two tables join with last table having optional rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables in my database which are organized as follow

--> Articles(ArticleID,UserID,ArticleCategory,ArticleTitle,ArticleBody,ArticleIsActive)

--> ArticleImages(ArticleImageID,ArticleID,ArticleImageExtension)

**Scenario:**

=> A user wants to post an article, the user has the option to post the article with/without multiple images, when user post article with multiple images, the article details are stored in Articles table, Images name and extension are store in ArticleImages table along with the articleID as a reference

**Problem:**

=> When user post an article without images, the post data is stored in Articles table, but as there are no images, so no data is stored in ArticleImages Table, so when i loop through all the data on my Articles page, i use this query

```
  public function getAllHomeArticles(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('CI_Articles_Tbl');
  $this->db->join('CI_Article_Images_Tbl',
 'CI_Articles_Tbl.roflArticle_ID =
  CI_Article_Images_Tbl.roflArticle_ID');
  $this->db->group_by('CI_Articles_Tbl.roflArticle_ID');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
  }
```

I am joining two tables using ArticleID as join option, the problem is, with no images in ArticleImages table, i am unable to show those articles which dont have images, what is the best approach for showing all the articles having/notHaving images in ArticleImages table.

Any Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the join statement to this:

```
 $this->db->join('CI_Article_Images_Tbl', 'CI_Articles_Tbl.roflArticle_ID = CI_Article_Images_Tbl.roflArticle_ID', 'left');
```

Adding the left at the end to make a MySQL left join which will include all results from CI_Articles_Tbl and results from CI_Article_Images_Tbl where available unlike the default inner join which only returns results when they are present in both tables.

A good guide to understanding joins in MySQL can be found at: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: great answer Andy Platt!

Comment: There is a slight problem in LEFT JOIN now, it did fetched all records regardless of reference present or not in ArticleImages table, but now, the Mismatched ArticleID which is used as a Join Condition is not been fetched when there is a miss in Second table

Comment: Its being lost as it has the same name in both tables and is being overwritten by the second instance - expand your select to specify the fields to fetch and skip the second ArticleID as it is superfluous, ie:

Comment: $this->db->select('Articles.ArticleID,Articles.UserID,Articles.ArticleCategory,Articles.ArticleTitle,Articles.ArticleBody,Articles.ArticleIsActive,ArticleImages.ArticleImageID,ArticleImages.ArticleImageExtension');

Comment: ^--- That probably won't work because the example in your code has 'rofl' before the field names which is different from the names you specified at the start of the question, you'll need to adjust to what the names actually are.

Comment: Yeap Andy, while i was waiting for a reply from you, i posted a second question about the issue i faced, you can check out it here, and i answered it too when the problem got solved you can check it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418791/codeigniter-two-tables-left-join-does-not-return-join-condition-id-of-left-table

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted - good luck with your project =)